# How to output the strings line by line in text file?

Tags: html, windows, vbscript

I jsut made this htm working with vbs, but I enter something in testbox line by line, it output everything to the text file in one line.... How can I make the output line by line as same as the strings entered in textbox?

another question is is that possible to using only one button to "output" and "run batch" instead clicking twice?

Here is my code, save as `htm` file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Release To Production Files Sync To Mexico</title>

</head>

<script language="vbscript">

Sub WriteTxt_OnClick()
    Dim fso, txt

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txt = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\work\test.txt")

    txt.WriteLine document.Submitted_Link_To_Mex.body.value

    MsgBox "File Submitted",64,"Selection"


End Sub

Sub SYNC_onClick()
     Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
     WshShell.Run "C:\work\test.bat", 0
            ' 0 => hide cmd
     MsgBox("Success")

End Sub
</script>


<H2>Copy And Paste The Folder Path To Here </H2>
<body>


<form name="Submitted_Link_To_Mex">
<textarea name="body" cols="150" rows="20">

</textarea>
</form>

<br>
    <input type="button" value="1. SUBMIT" name="WriteTxt"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="Button" value="2. SYNC" name="SYNC"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's writing the data as a single line because you are stating for the program to write it as a single line. Yes when someone hit's "Enter" in a textarea, it separates lines by a newline component or in vbscript "vbcrlf".

So to fix this, you can go two routes.

Just write the entire content directly in a write block:

```
Sub WriteTxt_OnClick()
     Dim fso, txt

     Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     Set txt = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\work\test.txt")

     txt.Write document.Submitted_Link_To_Mex.body.value

     MsgBox "File Submitted",64,"Selection"


End Sub
```

The key being here : ".Write" instead of .WriteLine

Or

You can check the contents and split if necessary.

```
Sub WriteTxt_OnClick()
    Dim fso, txt

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txt = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\work\test.txt")
    dim tmp : tmp = document.Submitted_Link_To_Mex.body.value
    if instr(tmp, vbcrlf) then
    dim all_lines : all lines = split(tmp, vbcrlf)
    for each line in all_lines
    txt.WriteLine line
    next
    txt.Close
End Sub
```

And yes you can call a sub from another sub, it would be like this:

```
Sub Call_Sub1
    dim foo : foo = "i am horrible at deciphering bad english translations of dracula"
    Call_Sub2 foo
End Sub
Sub Call_Sub2(str)
    dim bar : bar = left(str, 40) 
End Sub
```